# How can i recover content of a List<DataRow> and turn into a List<string>

Tags: c#, list, datarow

I'm reading a Excel file and inserting the content of it on a `List<DataRow>` like this:

```
 DataSet ds = excelReader.AsDataSet();
        DataTable data = ds.Tables[0];
        List<DataRow> rows = data.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().ToList();
```

this is working just fine, but i need these contents on a `List<String>`

Comment: can you write the code to turn a single row into a string? how?

Comment: It would really help if you told us what “these contents” are and what string you want to turn them into.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figure it out by this code:

```
List<DataRow> pStrings //this is my populated list


int y = 0;
 foreach (DataRow str in pStrings)
            {
                 string value = str[y].ToString();
                y++;

            }
```

With this code i can get the value of each `DataRow`.
Thanks for all the answers

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna take the value of the first column

```
var rows = data.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(dr => dr[0].ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the OfType Linq method by doing something like:
`List<string> rowsAsString = rows.OfType<string>()`

This will attempt to cast each row to a string, however if the cast is invalid this will fail and you'd have to manipulate each row to get the expected output, similar to Milton's answer.  Without knowing exactly how you want the output formatted, I can't give you an exact answer for that.